# Kernel Panic on Ubuntu Boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I recently encountered a perplexing issue with my Ubuntu system during boot-up. After powering on, instead of the usual login screen, I was met with a series of error messages culminating in a kernel panic. I'm reaching out to the community in hopes that someone has come across this issue before and can guide me towards a resolution.

Here's the crux of the error message:

*/dev/root: Cant open blockdev

VFS: Cannot open root device "nvme0n1p2" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
CPU. 4 PID: Comm swapper80 Not tainted 6.2.0-35-generic #35-Ubuntu*

From my understanding, the system can't locate or mount the root file system. This has effectively left me unable to access my system.

If anyone has experienced this or a similar problem, or if you have suggestions on potential fixes, I would be immensely grateful for your insights. I've tried some basic troubleshooting, but so far, no luck.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: boot a rescue system (via USB or similar) and check the state of the noted disk. chroot into the system and reconfigure and reinstall grub is necessary.

Comment: Hello,

I've tried addressing a Kernel Panic issue without success:

    Chroot Attempt:
        Booted via a live USB.
        Mounted /dev/sda1 to /mnt, faced mounting issues.
        Attempted chroot into /mnt, got an error.

    Disk Analysis with lsblk:
        Found my system on nvme0n1 with nvme0n1p1 (512MB) and nvme0n1p2 (953GB).

    Chroot into OS:
        Mounted nvme0n1p2 to /mnt, chrooted, ran update commands. sudo update-initramfs -u -k $(uname -r)
sudo update-grub  Still facing the issue. Need further guidance. Thanks!

Comment: did you used the host cpu as guest cpu? Moreover, PVE uses other tools to update please [read the manual](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Host_Bootloader)